# why I can't show the icon next to text? I've tried so many methods and still doesn't work

Tags: html, css

Why I can't show the icon next to text? I've tried so many methods and still doesn't work.

This is my code and please check it. Thanks

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #444444;
}

li a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-right: 1px solid greenyellow;
  min-width: 80px;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #222222;
  color: #FFE400;
  animation: myGlowAnimation;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes myGlowAnimation {
  80% {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #FF7F50;
  }
}

li a:focus {
  color: orange;
}

body {
  background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/62/24/7f/62247f857425ed3f71abfaffd77605af.jpg');
  width: 1900px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DTtEP7lX0AAyK3N.jpg" style="height:40px; width:auto;border-radius:50%;">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Entertain</a></li>
  </ul>

</body>
```

.................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Keep everything together in your post and add a snippet. Separate part of your code aren't answers.

Comment: Welcome! Please, consider adding the style.css code you have tried too. Also, you repeated the inclusion of your style.css in the head of your html.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can do here:

1. Use `display:inline` on your `li` element/ icon etc.
2. Float your icon to left.

In following snippet i floated `img`(in your case icon) to left. And adjusted it using negative margin. Float CSS property places an element on the left or right side of its container, The element is removed from the normal flow of the page, though still remaining a part of the flowallowing text and inline elements to wrap around it.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #444444;
}

li a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-right: 1px solid greenyellow;
  min-width: 80px;
}

li a img{
  float:left;
  margin-top:-8px;
  margin-left:-20px;
  }

li a:hover {
  background-color: #222222;
  color: #FFE400;
  animation: myGlowAnimation;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes myGlowAnimation {
  80% {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #FF7F50;
  }
}

li a:focus {
  color: orange;
}

body {
  background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/62/24/7f/62247f857425ed3f71abfaffd77605af.jpg');
  width: 1900px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DTtEP7lX0AAyK3N.jpg" style="height:40px; width:auto;border-radius:50%;">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Entertain</a></li>
  </ul>

</body>
```

Comment: what's that mean?

Comment: i want to do like in this video, look at the icon please. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHFflWvii3M&list=LL&index=4&ab_channel=EasyTutorials